# How to slice pandas DataFrame based on values from another Dataframe without using for-loop?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vectorization, slice

I have a DataFrame `df1`:

```
df1.head() =    
             id    type    position
dates
2000-01-03  17378   600       400
2000-01-03   4203   600       150
2000-01-03  18321   600      5000
2000-01-03   6158   600      1000
2000-01-03    886   600     10000
2000-01-03  17127   600       800
2000-01-03  18317  1300       110
2000-01-03   5536   600       207
2000-01-03   5132   600     20000
2000-01-03  18191   600      2000
```

And a second DataFrame `df2`:

```
df2.head() = 

               dt_f       dt_l
id_y  id_x
670   715   2000-02-14 2003-09-30
704   2963  2000-02-11 2004-01-13
886   18350 2000-02-09 2001-09-24
1451  18159 2005-11-14 2007-03-06
2175  8648  2007-02-28 2007-09-19
2236  18321 2001-04-05 2002-07-02
2283  2352  2007-03-07 2007-09-19
      6694  2007-03-07 2007-09-17
      13865 2007-04-19 2007-09-19
      14348 2007-08-10 2007-09-19
      15415 2007-03-07 2007-09-19
2300  2963  2001-05-30 2007-09-26
```

I need to slice `df1`for each value of `id_x`, and count the number of rows within the interval `dt_f:dt_l`. This has to be done again for the values of `id_y`. Finally the result should be merged on `df2`, giving as output the following DataFrame:

```
df_result.head() = 

               dt_f       dt_l     n_x   n_y
id_y  id_x
670   715   2000-02-14 2003-09-30   8     10 
704   2963  2000-02-11 2004-01-13   13    25 
886   18350 2000-02-09 2001-09-24   32    75
1451  18159 2005-11-14 2007-03-06   48    6
```

where `n_x`(`n_y`) corresponds to the number of rows contained in the interval `dt_f:dt_l` for each value of `id_x(id_y`).

Here is the for-loop I have used:

```
idx_list = df2.index.tolist()
k = 1 
for j in idx_list: 
    n_y = df1[df1.id == j[0]][df2['dt_f'].iloc[k]:df2['dt_l'].iloc[k]]['id'].count() 
    n_x = df1[df1.id == j[1]][df2['dt_f'].iloc[k]:df2['dt_l'].iloc[k]]['id'].count()
```

Would it be possible to do it without using a for-loop? DataFrame `df1`contains around 30000 rows and I am afraid a loop will slow down the process too much, since this is a small part of the whole script.

Comment: Why is `n_y` different from `n_x`? Can you show us your `for` loop?

Comment: Are you happy with the current answer? As a side note, you should check how to post a [MCVE]. Ideally, your inputs would lead to your desired output, which would make it easier for people to check their answer (and also understand the question).

Comment: Thanks IanS for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want something like this:

```
#Merge the tables together - making sure we keep the index column
mg = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, left_on = 'id', right_on = 'id_x')

#Select only the rows that are within the start and end
mg = mg[(mg['index'] > mg['dt_f']) & (mg['index'] < mg['dt_l'])]

#Finally count by id_x
mg.groupby('id_x').count()
```

You'll need to tidy up the columns afterwards and repeat for id_y.

Comment: Many thanks! It works perfectly! ( I have adapted it to my code by reseting the index on both df's and and I using mg['dates'] instead of mg['index'])